# Deriving the ordinary kriging equations with noisy data

Tags: correlation, autocorrelation, data-imputation, variogram, kriging

I am trying to derive the ordinary kriging equations when I want to estimate the underlying value at $T(x_0)$ from the noisy observations at its neighbors $Z(x_1),....Z(x_n)$.

$Z(x_0) = T(x_0) + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ ~ $N(0,1)$

I was following the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging. where using the unbiasedness condition they derived that the sum of weights is equal to 1

$1^TW = 1$

Further to reduce the variance of the estimate that is 
$E(\epsilon(x_0)) = E(Z(x_0) -W^T(Z(x_1)...Z(x_n))$

they got the following optimization problem

$min_W W^TVar(Z_{x_i})W - Cov^T_{Z_{x_i},Z_{x_0}}.W - W^TCov^T_{Z_{x_i},T_{x_0}} + Var(Z_{x_0})$

But in my case I want to estimate the underlying variable $T(x_0)$ rather than noisy $Z(x_0)$

So my optimization problem will be

$E(\epsilon(x_0)) = E(T(x_0) -W^T(Z(x_1)...Z(x_n))$ and

$min_W W^TVar(Z_{x_i})W - Cov^T_{Z_{x_i},T_{x_0}}.W - W^TCov^T_{Z_{x_i},T_{x_0}} + Var(T_{x_0})$

However, if I minimize wrt to W to this new optimization problem, I will get the same thing. So I am a bit confused how to proceed. suggestions?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the model. The random field is assumed to have a *deterministic* term $T(x_0)$ plus a random noise $\epsilon$.

Comment: @juliohm. Yeah the random field is assume to be $T(x_0)$ + random noise $\epsilon_i$.  I wanted to know how the weights will look like in this case when I want to estimate the underlying value $T(x_0)$ insteald of $Z(x_0)$